# Grails and swf application

Tags: grails, resources, flash, resourcebundle

I want to execute a flash application from grails 2.3.1.

I have a probleme loading my swf file's dependencies from a gsp.

Firstly, I tried to put all file needed into my web-app folder, and it worked like a charm :

- wab-app

  - css
  - flash

    - index.html // <- Use for my first test.
    - flash.swf
    - prefs.xml
    - data-flash-folder

      - video-folder
      - txt-folder
      - xml-folder
      - intro.swf
      - main.swf
      - prefs.xml
      - static.xml

When I go to this url : `http://localhost:8080/application-name/flash/index.html`, all work like a charm.

So I decided to call it from a controller :

```
class FrontFlashController {
    def openFlash() {
    }
}
```

Here is my gsp calling flash :

```
<g:applyLayout name="frontFlash">
        <div id="flash-render">
                <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="1000" height="700" title="myFlash" >
                    <param name="movie" value="flash/flash.swf" />
                    <param name="FLASHVARS" value="idSession=rffcu96vn6j4tq3o56j1bgn5o7&lang=fr&xmlPath=prefs.xml">
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <embed src="/application-name/flash/flash.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="700" flashvars="idSession=rffcu96vn6j4tq3o56j1bgn5o7&module=module&maxchapter=6&gochapter=3&jeu=0&cumul=285"></embed>
                </object>
        </div>
</g:applyLayout>
```

When calling the action by this url : `http://localhost:8080/application-name/frontFlash/openFlash`, my file 'flash.swf' is correctly loaded but none of his dependencies.

Here my firebug stack :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/application-name/frontFlash/data-folder/static.xml"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/application-name/frontFlash/data-folder/textes/default_en.xml"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/application-name/frontFlash/data-folder/prefs.xml"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/application-name/frontFlash/data-folder/intro.swf"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/application-name/frontFlash/data-folder/main.swf"
```

**Seems to grails is looking directly into my folder view instead of swf file folder.**

How can I fix it ?

More, later I want to link swf ressource outside of my grails application, how can I do that ?

Snite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem adding `<base href="/application-name/flash/">` into my head.

Here my final version of **openFlash.gsp :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>FLASH</title>
        <base href="/application-name/flash/">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <g:if test="${flash}">
                <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="1000" height="700" title="Module">
                    <param name="movie" value="flash.swf" />
                    <param name="FLASHVARS" value="idSession=rffcu96vn6j4tq3o56j1bgn5o7&lang=fr&xmlPath=prefs.xml">
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <embed src="${g.createLinkTo(dir: 'flash', file: 'flash.swf')}" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="700" flashvars="idSession=rffcu96vn6j4tq3o56j1bgn5o7&maxchapitre=6&gochapitre=3&jeu=0&cumul=285"></embed>
                </object>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <g:if test="${flash.error}">
                    <br />
                    <div class="alert alert-error">${flash.error}</div>
                </g:if>
            </g:else>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `g.createLinkTo` in `src`, like

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" title="myFlash" >
    <param name="movie" value="flash/flash.swf" />
    <param name="FLASHVARS" value="idSession=rffcu96vn6j4tq3o56j1bgn5o7&lang=fr&xmlPath=prefs.xml">
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="${g.createLinkTo(dir: 'flash', file: 'flash.swf')}" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="idSession=rffcu96vn6j4tq3o56j1bgn5o7&module=module&maxchapter=6&gochapter=3&jeu=0&cumul=285"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Did not change anything :/